# If $\mu$ is a probability measure s.t. the characterizing function of $\mu$ maps a closed ball to $\{1\}$, then $\mu=\delta_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(E)$ of a normed vector space $E$, $B_{E'}$ denote the closed unit ball in $E'$ and $\hat\mu$ denote the characteristic function of $\mu$.

> Assume there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\tag1\hat\mu(\delta B_{E'})=\{1\}.$$ Why are we able to conclude $$\hat\mu(E')=\{1\}?\tag2$$

The claim should follow from the inequality $$\left|\hat\mu(\varphi_1)-\hat\mu(\varphi_2)\right|^2\le2\hat\mu(0)\left(\hat\mu(0)-\Re\hat\mu(\varphi_1-\varphi_2)\right);\;\;\text{for all }\varphi_i\in E'.\tag3$$ But how exactly?

Comment: Could you define the characteristic function of $\mu$?

Comment: Where did (4), (5), (6) come from?  Are you only interested in the case when $E$ is non-separable?  (If $E$ is separable, this follows from the case when $E = \mathbb{R}$ with a little work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first claim follows from (3) by induction: Let's show that $\hat \mu(2^n \delta B_{E'})=\{1\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. For $n=0$ this is true by assumption. For the induction step take $\phi\in 2^{n+1}\delta B_{E'}$. Since $\frac 1 2 \phi\in 2^{n}\delta B_{E'}$, we have $\hat \mu(2^{-1}\phi)=1$ by induction hypothesis. Therefore
$$
|\hat \mu(\phi)-1|^2=|\hat \mu(\phi)-\hat\mu(2^{-1}\phi)|^2\leq 2(1-\hat \mu(2^{-1}\phi))=0
$$
by (3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I'm not missing anything, your proof still works when $\mu$ is a finite signed measure ($(3)$ is then replaced by $$\left|\hat\mu(\varphi_1)-\hat\mu(\varphi_2)\right|^2\le2\hat{|\mu|}(0)\left(\hat{|\mu|}(0)-\Re\hat{|\mu|}(\varphi_1-\varphi_2)\right);\;\;\text{for all }\varphi_i\in E'.\tag{3'}$$ and under the assumption that $$\hat{|\mu|}(\delta B_{E'})=\{c\}\tag{1'}$$ for some $c\ge0$. It should then follow that $$\hat{|\mu|}(E')=\{c\}\tag{2'}.$$ Do you agree?

Comment: What can we conclude from this? It surely implies that $|\mu|=c\delta_0$, but what does that mean for $\mu$ itself?

Comment: The problem is that (1') only gives information about the characteristic function of $|\mu|$, while on the LHS of (3') there is still the characteristic function of $\mu$. So I don't think the same argument works without problems.

Comment: But don't we simply need to replace $\mu$ by $|\mu|$ in $(3')$ (noting that $||\mu||=|\mu|$)?

Comment: You're right. Also, from $|\mu|=c\delta_0$ one can conclude $\mu=\pm c\delta_0$.

Comment: Why can we make this conclusion? It seems obvious, but what's the formal argument?

Comment: You can look at the Hahn-Jordan decomposition for $\mu$. There are measurable sets $E_\pm$ such that $E_+\cap E_-=\emptyset$ and $\mu_\pm$ is supported on $E_\pm$. If $\mu_+$ gives positive measure to a subset of $E_+$ that does not contain $0$, then so does $|\mu|=\mu_++\mu_-$. The same applies to $\mu_-$, so that $\mu_+$ and $\mu_-$ must both be multiples of $\delta_0$ (because they are mutually singular, only one of them can be a non-zero multiple).